# How to implement matrix multiplication of UMat in opencv?

Tags: opencv

How to implement matrix multiplication of UMat in opencv

```
    UMat AA_J2,AAu,J2u;
    AA.copyTo(AAu);
    J_2.copyTo(J2u);
    AA_J2=AAu*J2u;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cv::gemm](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gacb6e64071dffe36434e1e7ee79e7cb35) to perform matrix multiplication, addition and more with cv::UMat.